# What is the difference between variability and variance?

Tags: differences

I could only find one result from [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110319032835AAs8Gkc), but the answer wasn't clear on the exact meaning of variability and how it is different from variance.

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: [variance](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/variance?q=variance) vs [variability](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/variable?q=variability#variable__17)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88348/is-variation-the-same-as-variancehttps://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88348/is-variation-the-same-as-variance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Variance* is a measure of *variability* found.

The temperature of a given place will be *variable*. If we measure the temperature over a given period, we will have a set of results. We can then calculate the *variance* of those results, giving us a measure of that variability.